# socket.io query string doesn't come though in namespace authorization

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm securing a namespace of my socket in socket.io and I'm attempting to authorize the connection with an id I will pass. The connection looks like this: `io.connect('/chat?id=abc123')` to connect to my chat namespace.

My authorization looks like

```
io.of('/chat).authorization(function(handshakeData, callback) {
    console.dir(handshakeData);

    chatdb.VerifyUserInfo(handshakeData.query.id, function(err, records) {
        if(err || records.length !== 1)
            callback(err, false);
        else
            callback(null, true)
}
```

Basically, when `console.dir(handshakeData)` runs I get the following output for query and url and I'm not 100% sure why my data is being omitted

```
query: { t: '1387341178191' },
url: '/socket.io/1/?t=1387341178191',
```

Its my understanding that t is a timestamp sent by default by socket.io... but where did my id go? I feel like I'm doing everything [by the book](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec) but I can't quite figure out whats up. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.